# How I can successfully run an AutoIT scripts on locked remote machine in GUI less mode from Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework, autoit, remote-desktop

I have a Jenkins pipeline which triggers a batch file on remote locked windows machine. This batch file triggers the automation test execution of robot framework scripts.

These scripts has AutoIT GUI launching steps and all these AutoIT steps are failing.

If I login to the test station remote. This test execution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

While using Autoit GUI-functions which interact with the Desktop/Windows, you have to be logged-in. Otherwise Autoit scripts will fail.

Comment: Thank You Xenobiologist for you reply. 

Is there any workaround to overcome this issue?

Comment: Like soyacz suggested. Maybe try to start commandline commands if possible. What is it really that Autoit does for you on those machines?

Comment: AutoIT starts a GUI simulator and enter some values on the text boxes available in the simulator GUi.

Answer (score 0):

Install VNC server on jenkins slaves that execute robot framework tests. Remember to log in into each VNC.

Also set automatic logging in to windows after computer reboot, so in case windows updates will restart jenkins slave it will automatically start VNC and log in.